# Help: ZX81 BASIC "Peek" function

Tags: memory, basic, zx81

I need a way to find if the character ('<') has hit a wall (Black pixel Graphic)

-On a ZX81 game.

I'm been looking at another game... which uses code

```
if peek(peek 16398 +256*peek 16399) = code "**blackpixel graphic**" then ...
```

Which seems to work for them...

Is this correct code?

I'm not really knowledgable with addresses and getting memory and stuff.

Please help me...

-If you know a better way. Please answer :)

Thanks,

Comment: No help from me; I flushed that info from my memory about 20 years ago. :-)

Comment: xD :P Yeah I want to know the basics to pre-modern computing :) -Laying foundations...

Comment: "I want to know the basics to pre-modern computing " Then Try ZX-Spectrum instead. Much more fun + a good reason to learn a bit of Z80 assembly. you could try to make another driller(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driller_(video_game)), hard driving(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_driving) or another Elite(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_(video_game)) on spectrum. With text only display you'll be stuck with making rogue-likes(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) at best.

Comment: I've already got a ZX81 now xD *I'll see how I get on :)

Comment: Perhaps this helps (if it is still of interest in 2021): [Mastering Machine Code on Your ZX81](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~thunor/mmcoyzx81/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

`peek` reads the byte at a memory location. According to [The System Variables of the Sinclair ZX81](http://www.penelope.demon.co.uk/zx81/sysvars.html), memory location `16398` and `16399` form a 16bit value containing the current *"Address of PRINT position in display file"*.

Thus, `peek 16398 + 256*peek 16399` combines the two values into a 16 bit address and `peek`ing that address (possibly) gets the pixel/character(?) at that position.

Comment: Yeah i've been looking at that. No help to a beginner though. =/

Answer (score 2):

Located at addresses 16398 and 16399 are two bytes that form the cursor location. (See http://web.ukonline.co.uk/sinclair.zx81/chap28.html). In other words,

```
peek 16398 + 256*peek 16399
```

gives you the memory address of the character on the screen where the next PRINT would go. Which apparently can be changed with `PRINT AT`.

```
peek(peek 16398 + 256*peek 16399)
```

finds the code for whatever character is at that location. The rest you should be able to figure out.

Now, the main question is: does your game use the cursor in the same way? If not you have to use a different solution.

Comment: Hmmm ok so if I print a black pixel graphic at 10,10 (or any position) 'peek(peek 16398 + 256*peek 16399)' will find the code for a black pixel graphic?

Comment: No, it will find the code for whatever graphic is at the current cursor position.

Comment: Cursor position? Huh? :P I never knew ZX81's had mouses or cursors?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the memory address is, but peek usually means "what value is in this memory location?"

[This](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tzSwAFY3Y94J:www.fastchip.net/howcomputerswork/p1.html+memory+tutorial&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) looks like it should be some good reading in this particular topic.