# ZX81 ‘BASIC’ peek function

Tags: peek, zx81

I want to find the code of a character printed.

This is the code:

```
10 Print AT 2,2; "T"
20 Let C=Peek(Peek 16398+256*Peek 16399)
30 Print Peek(C)
```

It should just print the Code value of T.

I could later use:

```
40 Print Peek (Code C)
```

Or something.

But the 10-30 bit doesn't work. It always returns '0' -With different letters too: G,T 'black graphic' and M,

What am I doing wrong?

Will be used for collision detection.

Comment: This is just a test to see if it works. :) Not a full program :P

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196853/help-zx81-basic-peek-function ?

Comment: That is a question. This is a question to a response to that question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help: ZX81 BASIC "Peek" function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195111/help-zx81-basic-peek-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jdehaan's right, printing the `T` without a trailing `;` will move the cursor down to the next line after printing. (With `;`, it's be one position to the right.)

To read the character you'd just written you'd have to move back a position again:

```
PRINT AT 2,2;"T";AT 2,2;
PRINT PEEK(PEEK 16398+PEEK 16399*256)
```

gives me `57`, which is the character code for T.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.penelope.demon.co.uk/zx81/sysvars.html) it is the right address to peek, but maybe the cursor is not at the right position? If I remember well (man, what are you doing with that old thing :-) ! ) the PRINT AT might move the cursor one position after the printed char (or one line under).